# An application is playing music and I cannot find it

Tags: music

I double clicked an audio file a while ago and music began playing, but I cannot find the controls. It's been on shuffle, and I cannot turn it off.

Sometimes a notification box appears, but I cannot click it because it dims when I hover.

Comment: Click on the volume icon in the top bar. Is an application listed in it?

Answer (score 3):

Run the command

```
ps aux | grep pulse
```

Then get the ID of process running the pulse-audio, then kill it

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

for example:

```
$ ps aux | grep pulse
maythux  11058  0.0  0.0   9452   944 pts/2    S+   08:45   0:00 grep --color=auto pulse
maythux  11946  0.2  0.0 558100  7992 ?        S<l  May26   2:19 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

here I can see the 11946 as PID of pulse-audio then i kill it using

```
sudo kill -9 11946
```

Or easily just run the command

```
sudo pkill pulseaudio
```